# Android Studio is showing a popup window in the code editor. How can I get rid of it?

Tags: android-studio

I'm using `Android Studio Arctic Fox Preview` and it started to show me these popup windows in the editor displaying code that is currently out of my view. I couldn't find the name of this feature anywhere. How is it called and how do I make it go away?

[image]

Comment: did you solve it somehow?

Comment: by removing it and installing the stable version

Comment: I have the latest stable version and this super annoying feature is there too... It even goes beyond the Android Studio Window - it sometimes appears on my second screen!

Comment: I have this exact same problem and posted about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682622/android-studio-strange-code-sub-windows-after-upgrade-to-arctic-fox-2020-3-1 - I sure would like to fix this. I have Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.

Comment: See answer in my comment link just above.

Answer (score 4):

As [JJJones_3860](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2184214/jjjones-3860) mentioned in his comment, there's an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682622/android-studio-strange-code-sub-windows-after-upgrade-to-arctic-fox-2020-3-1) which seems to work and here it is:

> Navigate to:
>
> File > Settings... > Editor > Code Editing
>
> under Refactorings > Specify refactoring options:
>
> select In modal dialogs
>
> Press OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of Android Studio (Arctic Fox).
When your IDE is showing a popup window, you need to restart your IDE.

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart