# Cannot Hide Popup extracted method in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

- When I extract the code area by shortcut it always shows this bar and it cannot be hidden.

**Android studio version:** Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1

Comment: Which Shortcut you use?

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal : I use mac which shortcut is [option] + [cmd] + [M].

Comment: yes,i have same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think those other questions show same issue as yours:

- [Android Studio strange code sub-windows after upgrade to Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682622/android-studio-strange-code-sub-windows-after-upgrade-to-arctic-fox-2020-3-1)
- [Android Studio is showing a popup window in the code editor. How can I get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238377/android-studio-is-showing-a-popup-window-in-the-code-editor-how-can-i-get-rid-o)

[Answer by Chris Clarke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748331/5327495) is what worked for me, credit goes to him:

Navigate to:

*File > Settings... > Editor > Code Editing*

under

*Refactorings > Specify refactoring options:*

select

*In modal dialogs*

Press OK.

Comment: It worked for me after reinit the Android Studio