# Android Studio: How to remove the yellow "some changed lines popup"?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

How to get rid of this pop-up?

[image: screenshot of pop-up]

Some time ago, Android Studio started to show some recently-changed lines with a yellow background at the bottom of the window. On small screens this is really annoying. It seems to be some arbitrary lines I changed recently. When I click on it (left- or right-click), I jump to the location of shown lines in the editor. The pop-up then disappears, as well as when I normally navigate to the location. It re-appears when I scroll away, but not when I switch files; however, when it's already there it doesn't disappear when switching files, either.

Especially on small screens, this is very annoying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Hide Popup extracted method in Android Studio Arctic Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855901/cannot-hide-popup-extracted-method-in-android-studio-arctic-fox)

Comment: It does, thanks!